# Get Value from localStorage and append to iframe URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, local-storage

I'm trying to retrieve a value from `localStorage` and append it into an iframe URL and then write that out onto the page.

I'm trying to render the iframe with `document.write` but I don't think I'm doing it correctly.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $( ".postid-192" ).load(function() {
          var email = localStorage.getItem("email");
          document.write('<iframe src="http://www2.site.com/l/123/2009-04-28/ABCDE?email=' + email + ' width="1" height="1"></iframe>');
      });
  });
</script>
```

I guess I'm kinda confused on what `document.write` *should* do? I kinda got the impression that it would write out on the page...somewhere. But I might be going about this incorrectly. Overall, I'm trying to get value (in this case email) and just append it into the iframe URL and then have that placed on the page somewhere. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Never use `document.write()` unless there is absolutely no alternative. Try `document.body.appendChild()` instead. Also note that `load()` as an event handler is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML.

So don't use `document.write`. This code is correct:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".postid-192").load(function() {
        var email = localStorage.getItem("email");
        $("#iframe").html('<iframe src="http://www2.site.com/l/123/2009-04-28/ABCDE?email=' + email + '" width="1" height="1"></iframe>');
    });
});
</script>
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="iframe"></div>
```

Comment: You aren't closing the double quotes for the src attribute either.

Comment: @DavidMoškoř - Is this supposed to append the src to the iframe? Wait...NM...I see it now

Comment: @DavidMoškoř - Yep! I had to update one small thing, but it doing what it's supposed to now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to append a iframe:

```
var i=document.createElement('iframe');
i.src= 'http://www2.site.com/l/123/2009-04-28/ABCDE?email=' + email;
i.width=1;
i.height=1;
document.body.appendChild(i);
```